# How does LaTeX calculate the width of a caption? What is it based on?

Tags: floats, captions

A pretty straighforward question...

I thought of it while using the `caption` package, where you can set the width parameter for a caption. I am wondering if there is a better (smarter) way-perhaps the "LaTeX" way of calculating the ideal width for a caption based on the width of the figure/table/other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{width=.6\textwidth}
\begin{document}
\captionof{table}{Here is a beautifully typeset table. It is special because it is invisible to the naked eye.}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Here is a simple table with a standard \LaTeX{} caption. (That seems to be affected by the captionsetup command.)}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us how you determine the "ideal" width of figures and tables.

Comment: The traditional way in LaTeX is to put the caption in a box and measure it. However, this is only relevant in terms of the text block, not the image width.

Comment: @Mico Hey Mico, that is what I am asking YOU :). How does LaTeX calculate the width of captions?

Comment: The maximum width is the current linewidth. Using captionsetup, you can make the current linewidth shorter, hence the caption is not as wide.

Comment: By default, LaTeX doesn't "optimize" the caption width. The *maximum*  possible width simply is the width of the text block.

Comment: It is just the width of the caption text, if it is short, or the width of a standard line of text if it is long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX computes the caption width with a very simple algorithm: if the caption is less than the text width long, it is centered, otherwise it is set as a normal paragraph using the whole text width.

When `caption` is loaded, you can specify a different “normal” width with `width=`, `margin=` or other package features. However, the behavior is exactly the same, unless you also add `singlelinecheck=false`, so that the “center if the caption fits in one line” step is not performed.

Inside a `minipage`, the `\textwidth` parameter denotes the stated width of the `minipage`, so you can use this feature, if you want that your captions are measured with respect to the image size:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\captionsetup{width=.8\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Example image, with more text just to show that
  it wraps.}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we reword to linewidth?

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't understand. These are the correct parameters, assuming one column typesetting.

Comment: Yep, exactly. But i was thinking of two-column typesetting, making it more general.

Comment: @Johannes_B That will depend on two- or one-column floats. I'd simply avoid this, actually.